statusBarsPadding with edgeToEdge doesn't include status bar padding

Hello. When I use statusBarPadding with edgeToEdge, it doesn't unclude padding of status bar itself. If I remove statusBarPadding, snackbar will be above screen.
Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier
            .imePadding()
            .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background),
        floatingActionButton = fab,
        bottomBar = bottomBar,
        snackbarHost = {
            SnackbarHost(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .statusBarsPadding()
                    .fillMaxSize(),
                hostState = snackbarHostState,
                snackbar = { snackbarData ->
                    Snackbar(
                        snackbarData = snackbarData,
                        contentColor = Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                        containerColor = snackbarContainerColor,
                        actionContentColor = Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                        actionColor = Color(0xFFFFFFFF)
                    )
                }
            )
        },
    ) { paddingValues ->
        content(paddingValues)
    }

